# How to get the session ID that my model is attached to?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

This is my ORM object:

```
my_model = models.MyModel.find_by_id(1)
```

How do I get the SQLAlchemy session number that this object is attached to?

Answer (score 5):

To get the session ID:

```
my_model._sa_instance_state.session_id
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the use case for this, compared to retrieving the session itself [using inspection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState.session) or [`object_session()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä To debug error messages saying that "object attached to session N1 this is session N2".